# nginx location regexp for query string

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, nginx, webserver

I want to redirect anything that comes directly to my server with perticuler query string to other location in same domain.

If  user comes to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/?abc=js9sd70s
```

I want to redirect it to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/otherpath/?abc=js9sd70s
```

the query string `?abc=js9sd70s` should be the same to new url.

Please suggest nginx config file.

I have tried most of the alternative for below code. by keeping '\' before ? and = sign.

```
        location ~ /?abc=.* {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/otherpath/$1 permanent;
        }
```

Please suggest me this location change.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Short answer, try this configuration:

```
location = / {
    if ( $arg_abc ) {
        rewrite ^ /otherpath/ permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it redirected `www.mydomain.com/?abc=js9sd70s` to `www.mydomain.com/otherpath/?abc=js9sd70s` but now It is trying to redirect `www.mydomain.com/otherpath/?abc=js9sd70s` again and again, and it is not getting completed. Thanks for this help

Comment: can I put special check for `?abc` is at domain root, then and only this redirection rule applies? like in this case `www.mydomain.com/?abc=js9sd70s` should redirected but `www.mydomain.com/otherpath/?abc=js9sd70s` should not be.

Comment: The rule above working only in domain root, use:

location = / {

documentation: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location

Comment: ok, Do I need to separate `location /otherpath/` from `location /` in nginx config file? till now I have just one segment `location / { #rewrite code }` in config.

Comment: Please! Be carefull! location / and location = / it's a different locations! Read documentation first.

Comment: @SergeiLomakov you look very experienced on Nginx, can u help me problem here https://serverfault.com/questions/1035805/how-to-serve-php-on-nginx-on-a-query-parameter-amp-1